# List of Related Multi-Grams

Tags: word, knowledge, anagram

Each item on this list is a multi-word anagram. I like to call them Multi-Grams. Each line is a separate item in the list. For each item, rearrange the letters to form new words. The number of words in each item is unchanged. The items are all related to each other in some way. How many of them can you identify?

**STADIUM BOTCH

SIR DORSAL HE FAKE TROT

HATH LET PENNAME

WHY ASHTRAY ERN MELL

AM OINKED FLIGHT

HIGH TOAD FEN VIGIL TEND

FLEE SABBATH TRUCK

NINTH BUTT MONEY YOU**

Happy Multi-Gramming!

Comment: I'm not sure I get it.... Also what is an "item"? A word? A line?

Comment: An item is a line. Each line is a self-contained multi-word anagram.

Comment: This is another new puzzle type idea I'm trying. I'm sure it will need some fine tuning... :)

Comment: Within 1 line, we must make new words using all the letters? Or we make new line of words? Or we just use some letters?

Comment: For each line, you take all the letters and rearrange them to form new words. The number of words is retained. I appreciate the questions! :D

Comment: I added some clarification to the instructions in the post. Feel free to make any edits that you think make the puzzle more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After solving one and understanding the theme, the rest just came naturally. Had to google 2-3 i didn't know though.

> It is a list of movies.
>
> Answers in the same order:
>
>  - About Schmidt
>  - Raiders of The Lost Ark
>  - The Elephant Man
>  - When Harry Met Sally
>  - The Flamingo Kid
>  - Night of the Living Dead
>  - The Breakfast Club
>  - Mutiny On The Bounty

Comment: Holy cow! Nice work!!!!

Comment: It is fun, but a little easy, if you know the movies that is XD. I never heard of the elephant and flamingo ones. Sorry not many people had the time to see and try it. Feel free to delay giving the correct answer so more people come try and enjoy your puzzle if you want.

Comment: Oh yeah I hadn't thought of that. I guess I'm not very patient! :)

Comment: @wildBillMunson having the same number of words as the answer was a lifesaver though. Would have been quite hard otherwise. Must have taken you a lot of time to make it work so perfectly.

Comment: Yes haha it took me a couple hours to put together. Honestly since this was new I didn't know how solvable it was. Of course, you can solve pretty much anything :)

Comment: @wildBillMunson anagrams tend to get solved pretty fast on this website, which is why they are usually used as a stepping stone for a bigger puzzle while keeping the anagram tag hidden or undercover inside the wordplay tag XD

Comment: As you may know, I've been working on new puzzle types like Add-A-Grams and now Multi-Grams. Eventually I'd like to concatenate these types into a more complex puzzle. :D